# Unable to read cookie across subdomains (owa_cookie)

Tags: javascript, oracle, cookies

In my production environment, my front end is on a.example.com and my back end is on b.example.com:

I'm creating a cookie in .example.com domain in path '/' using javascript for it to be read from any subdomain.

When I try to read the cookie from b.example.com domain from Oracle using owa_cookie it gives the error no_data_found.

I looked at the contents of the cookie in my browser and I could see it:

Domain .example.com

Path /

---

In my test environment, my front end and back end are on the same subdomain b.example.com. Here the Oracle Application server is able to read the cookie with the exact same code.

What am I doing wrong? From what I've read, I just need to store the cookie in .example.com for it to be read from any subdomain. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you setting any expiry to the cookies? Or are they strictly session cookies?

Comment: Use a tool like Tamper Data to check if the cookie is really send to the server.

Comment: Yes, Ates. I'm setting the cookie to expire in 3 minutes before calling the Oracle httpservice. But I can see the cookie in Firefox when I click on "Show cookie" after my service returns a message that it was unable to read the cookie.

Comment: Thanks, h3xstream. Great idea. I will try it and find out.

Comment: h3xstream, I'm confused... what should I check for? When the Oracle httpservice is called, the Tamper Data popup appears displaying the cookie contents as well as the parameters that are passed to the service. 

But doesn't that only tell me that the javascript has successfully written the cookie and not whether the Oracle httpservice can read it?

The reason I'm asking this is even when other Oracle services are called after it that do not read the cookie, the cookie contents can be seen in the Tamper Data popup window.

Comment: Thank you both, especially h3xstream. When I carefully looked at the cookie I noticed the name was subtly different:) (it was due to a test). Finally a logical outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write/read cookies across subdomains, you just need to save it in .example.com. The issue was something else - it was a name mismatch. Thanks folks.