# Cookies not included in cross-domain AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, rest, cookies

My JavaScript app communicates with a RESTful API that I built which lives on another domain. Locally, the API (Sinatra-based) lives at localhost:9292, and the web site is at localhost:3000.

In production, the API is at api.mydomain.com, and the web site is at admin.mydomain.com.

Everything is fine in local dev mode...cookies are sent to the API with each AJAX request when I look at the "headers" tab for requests under Chrome. However, in production mode, cookies simply are not sent with requests. And the cookie does in fact exist for admin.mydomain.com.

I understand the following JavaScript should make cookies be sent cross-domain with requests -- am I missing something?

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  options.crossDomain = {
    crossDomain: true
  };
  options.xhrFields = {
    withCredentials: true
  };
});
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to read cookie across subdomains (owa\_cookie)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094318/unable-to-read-cookie-across-subdomains-owa-cookie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set cookie domain to ".mydomain.com" with leading dot.